# Usage Map from ROSCon 2014?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey for those of you who were at ROSCon 2014 in Chicago there was a slick looking demo showing how many usage statistics of different packages, number of bugs, etc. I think it also showed a map of users geographically. I think it might have been demoed during a lightning talk, not sure.

I am NOT referring to this map: http://metrorobots.com/rosmap.html

Anyone know what I'm talking about or where it's located?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199035/usage-map-from-roscon-2014?/) by [csherstan](https://answers.ros.org/users/9751/csherstan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2014-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean "The ROS ecosystem: Impact, insights, and improvements"?
[Slides](http://roscon.ros.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/The-ROS-ecosystem-Impact-insights-and-improvements.pdf), [Video](http://vimeo.com/106993915)

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-12-08**:
Here's a link to the ecosystem graph:

http://http404error.github.io/roseco/graph.html?id=ros.json

**Comment by [csherstan](https://answers.ros.org/users/9751/csherstan/) on 2014-12-09**:
Yup, Ryan and Tom for the win. Thanks guys.